# Solving $ 4^{x^3−x+2}⋅5^{2x−3x^2}−2^{4−3x^2}⋅25^{x^3}\geq 0 $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, real-numbers

> The inequality is 
>   $$ 4^{(x^3−x+2)}⋅5^{(2x−3x^2)}−2^{(4−3x^2)}⋅25^{(x^3)}\geq 0 $$

So I simplified this inequality a bit
$$2^{(2x^3−2x+4)}⋅5^{(2x−3x^2)} \geq  2^{(4−3x^2)}⋅5^{(2x^3)}$$

However I am still unable to find solution.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your issue is equivalent to $\ln(LHS) \geq \ln(RHS)$ because $\ln$ function is increasing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now $${2^{(2x^3−2x+4)}\over  2^{(4−3x^2)}} \geq {5^{(2x^3)}\over 5^{(2x−3x^2)}}$$

so $$2^{2x^3+3x^2-2x}\geq 5^{2x^3+3x^2-2x}$$

or $$1\geq \left({5\over 2}\right)^{2x^3+3x^2-2x}$$

so $$0\geq 2x^3+3x^2-2x = x(2x^2+3x-2)$$ and so on...

Comment: thank you very much for this solution